# Is the ring $S=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & a\\ \end{pmatrix} \in M_2(R) \right\}$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am trying to proove if $S=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & a\\ \end{pmatrix} \in M_2(R) \right\}$ is a field. My thought is that due to the fact that $\det=0$ for every a different than $0$ that means that there arent inverse matrices. But in a teachers' solution said: the inverse is \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/a \\ \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Once you have established what the addition and multiplication in $S$ are, you see immediately that $S$ is isomorphic as a ring to $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, so is $S$. I think that's what @Sumanta wanted to say as a hint in his deleted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of “inverse” in a field depends on the identity element. The meaning of “inverse” in the field $S$ will be different from the meaning of “inverse” in $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb R)$ because the two fields have different identity elements.

The standard identity matrix in $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb R)$ is
$$I=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
However, $I$ is not even an element of the field $S$. $S$ has its own different identity matrix:
$$I_S=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
We know that this is in fact an identity matrix because it preserves the identity of any other matrix in $S$ that it is multiplied with:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a\end{pmatrix} $$
Note that $I_S$ does not need to preserve the identity of *all* matrices under multiplication, because $S$ does not consist of *all* matrices. It is not too hard to verify that $I_S$ is the unique identity matrix of $S$.

The inverse of a matrix $A\in S$ equals the unique matrix $B$ satisfying $AB=BA=I_S$, *not* $AB=BA=I$. Notice that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/a\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/a\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

Which demonstrates why your teacher’s assertion was correct.

Comment: Thank you. That explains a lot. Thank you again

Comment: @MargaritaPapavlasopoulou No problem! If you found it helpful, don’t forget to $\uparrow$ and $\checkmark$! And welcome to Math Stackexchange! :)